# CodeIgniter + FB PHP SDK + mod rewrite to remove index.php = disaster

Tags: php, facebook, apache, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I added the following to my CodeIgniter project to my .htaccess in order to remove the index.php:

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Everything worked fine. My URLs no longer need index.php in the.

However, this has created an interesting side effect such that when I try to login using Facebook OAuth, I get the following error:

> The webpage at
>   =">https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fsign_in%2Ffacebook%2F&state=8f3d1e5de60e47935460564a41f35af3&scope=email#*=*
>   has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this
>   site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it
>   is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your
>   computer.

NOTE: client id and redirect URI have been changed for privacy.

I'm using the PHP SDK 3.1.1 https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk and followed the sample code on http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/. When I still had index.php in my URLs, everything worked fine. The problem seem to have started after I added the the rewrite rules to remove index.php.

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to following patch:
In system/core/config.php file, in site_url method replace the following line 
return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->slash_item('index_page').$this->_uri_string($uri).$suffix;
with new code:
return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->_uri_string($uri).$suffix;

It might get working...

Comment: What is this supposed to do? I don't think I want to touch the core.